# How does backpropagation work with averaging layers?

Tags: neural-network, word-embeddings, word2vec, rnn

I'm studying Word2Vec algorithm, and so far i understood that, in the case of input context bigger than 1 (so multiple words) we have our hidden layer that performs averaging between the inputs (as explained here: [Word2Vec CBOW](https://www.knime.com/blog/word-embedding-word2vec-explained))

I didn't understand how does backpropagation work in this case.

When i start backpropagating from the softmax output layer and i reach for the hidden layer in my process, am i coping the weight over all the "*same position*" inputs?

To make my question clearer, if i have 2 context words coded as one hot vectors and i call the first weight of the first word as `W11` and the first weight of the second word as `W21`, when i'm backpropagating, those two weights will be updated with se same value, right?

Answer (score 1):

**Highly unlikely.**

Simple thought experiment. If the vertices (graphically == weights) are the same for these two nodes (first cell of the vector for the first word and the first cell of the vector for the second word in context) (what I am trying to say they are fully connected) **BUT** input values when you feed-fowarded these values were different, not only that this difference spaned accros other layers, hence you can not expect that weight updates via backprop will be same.

Comment: So how does the backpropagation work in the case of an averaging layer? In the forward pass the output of my hidden layer (the one mentioned in the link) is the average of all the inputs received from the single hidden neuron.
What happens when i start backpropagating and i have to update all those weights which were averaged?